# store a pattern1 line in buffer and use it to replace the pattern2

Tags: sed

file:

```
url: urlvalue
name: 
organisation:
word
```

How can i extract urlvalue and add it to name: so that final output will be.

```
url: urlvalue
name: urlvalue
organisation:
word
```

regex to find a pattern and make a duplicate but by editing the first word of pattern
eg. in above find for line with ^url below that line add duplicate of the same line but change url: to name:

Also query regarding below:
How can i negate multiple regex in awk or sed ?

eg. all lines that dont start with name, organisation, and url ---> apped pass: as prefix to those lines

Tried:

```
awk '$1 != "url*" && $1 != "name*" && $1 != "organisation*" {$1 = "pass"} {print}'
```

Also tried:

```
awk '$1 != "url*" && $1 != "name*" && $1 != "organisation*" {gsub(/^/, pass:, "g", $1) {print}'
```

Not working

Another Tried solution Works partially

```
awk '$1 != "url:" && $1 != "name:" && $1 != "organisation:" {print "pass"$0}'
```

But it outputs only

```
pass:word
```

Desired output :

```
url: urlvalue
name: urlvalue
organisation:
pass:word
```

Comment: ```sed 's/^url: \(.*\)$/: \1/; /^name: *$/d' a.txt``` - add new line ```name: \1``` and delete ```name:```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that any existing lines beginning with `name:` can be ignored, and you simply want to duplicate every `url:` line with `url:` changed to `name:`, the following may be suitable:

```
$ sed -n '/^name:/!p; s/^url:/name:/p' file
url: urlvalue
name: urlvalue
organisation:
```

`-n` to disable automatic printing. `p`rint any lines that do not start with "name:". Then using the `p` flag with the `s///` command, print lines that started with "url:" having changed it to start with "name:".

The same idea with `awk`:

```
$ awk '!/^name:/; sub(/^url:/, "name:")' file
url: urlvalue
name: urlvalue
organisation:
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it worked

```
awk '$1 != "url:" && $1 != "name:" && $1 != "organisation:" {gsub(/^/,"pass:",$1)} {print}'
```